How do I suppress a `SecretsUsedInArgOrEnv` warning from Docker
I am using Docker version 27.2.0 from Docker Desktop 4.34.3 on a Mac (darwin/arm64). Since upgrading, I now get this warning when building my Docker image:
 1 warning found (use docker --debug to expand):
 - SecretsUsedInArgOrEnv: Do not use ARG or ENV instructions for sensitive data (ENV "CHAMBER_KMS_KEY_ALIAS") (line 20)

The ENV variable CHAMBER_KMS_KEY_ALIAS is not a secret. It is usually the default value aws/ssm and even if it were not, it is just the name of the key, not access to the key, which is protected.
How do I suppress this warning?

Preferably, there would be a way to indicate that CHAMBER_KMS_KEY_ALIAS is not a secret, while continuing to enable warnings about secrets.
Failing that, how do I disable warnings about secrets altogether?

The documentation does not indicate how to do it, or even what it is actually looking for. My guess is that it is flagging that the variable name contains KEY.
I do not want to change the name of the variable because it is used by a program I do not have control over. If I change the name in the Dockerfile, I would then have to hack in some sort of startup script to copy the value over to the right variable, which is an even bigger security headache.

Start your Dockerfile with:
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1
# check=skip=SecretsUsedInArgOrEnv

Unfortunately it seems like you can't ignore a single warning.
Source: https://docs.docker.com/build/checks/
